# Form submitted to Web Api Get(string id) is repeated until ::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api site and I am trying to call a controller and have it return a zip file from the server. I submit a form to my Web Api site using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("downloadSettings").submit();
```

The action on the controller is defined as:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
```

The form being submitted has an input that has the expected value (id). I submit the form, the controller receives the call, performs the action (fetches the requested file as `byte[]`), and attempts to return the file like this:

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(fileContents))
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "fileName.zip";       
    return response;
}
```

Simply running the code ends in me receiving an error - `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.
If I debug the Get action, what I see is - **the moment the `Get` function finishes, a new thread arrives at the beginning of the function!** There is no new call being made from the browser (the Network tab shows no new calls), and yet, the function is repeated several times over until suddenly it doesn't and on the client (browser) I get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

What is going on? How do I fix it? Am I doing something wrong in the way I am attempting to return the file?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was the `using([...])`.
Once I removed that from the MemoryStream, everything went swimmingly!

I still do wonder though... what was up with the repeat calls?